# Bean Validation (ConstraintValidator) + CDI + Tomcat 8: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call

Tags: hibernate, validation, tomcat, cdi, weld

In a JSF application running on Tomcat: Using `@Inject` in a `ConstraintValidator` results in a `javax.validation.ValidationException`: *HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.*

Elsewhere in the application, CDI works without errors.

The `ConstraintValidator`:

```
public class MyIntervalValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyInterval, Integer> {

    @Inject
    private Interval interval;

    public void initialize(MyInterval myIntervall) {
    }

    public boolean isValid(Integer i, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {

        Integer ceiling;

        ceiling = interval.getCeiling();

        if ((0 <= i) && (i <= ceiling)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I checked the injection: `interval` is `null` during the execution of the method `isValid`.

The `Interval`:

```
@SessionScoped
public class Interval implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Min(value = 1)
    private Integer ceiling;

    public Interval() {
        this.ceiling = 1;
    }

    public Integer getCeiling() {
        return ceiling;
    }

    public void setCeiling(Integer ceiling) {
        this.ceiling = ceiling;
    }

}
```

The `context.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context>
    <Resource name="BeanManager" 
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
        factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory" />
</Context>
```

Detail from the `web.xml`:

```
<resource-env-ref>
   <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
   <resource-env-ref-type>
      javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
   </resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

**Information regarding the environment:**

- Maven
- Tomcat 8 via Eclipse Neon
- CDI: `weld-servlet-core` (2.4.1.Final; empty `bean.xml` in folder `WEB-INF`)
- Bean Validation: `hibernate-validator` (5.3.3.Final)
- JSF: `com.sun.faces` (2.2.14)

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the Hibernate Validator CDI integration module in your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Maybe this is missing in your setup?

Comment: Hi Christian. Many Thanks for your hint. However, I had already inserted this dependency. Unfortunately, the behavior has not changed. The same exception is thrown. Is further configuration necessary?